# Multiple lined UIAlertController message

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

Is there a way to format the message (not the title) string of a UIAlertController to show multiple lines? I've tried the "/n" character and that doesn't work. I also can't use NSString and formatting it.

Thanks!

Edit: d'oh it should have been \n not /n. Here's the correct code

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "blah", message: "1. blah \n2. blah \n3. blah", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
```

Comment: It's `\n`, not `/n`. And [edit] your question with some relevant code.

Comment: Can you add your code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will work with `\n` as edited.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title",
                              message: "message: \n message",
                              preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
                                 style: .cancel, handler: nil)

alert.addAction(cancelAction)
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: How to handle if you receive from some webservices ? Please checkout this question.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46212166/all-the-alert-dialog-message-and-textfield-have-been-changed-to-single-line-ple