# UiAlertMultiple Line issue in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

Why text show in single Line in my whole app

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "PayPal", message: "With PayPal processing fee total amount is . Do you want to proceed?", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

}))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

}))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Comment: It's already displayed in multiple line

Comment: I am asking about Message.
Paypal is Title its always show different. By default message also show multiple Line, Alert box size increase automatically but now its show in single line

Comment: Yes, I check your code in my project it displays multiple lines of text for message  Even then try by adding **\n** between your message text.

Comment: All Message come from backend service. and its not a correct way to handle this issue

Comment: Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/49026523/10150796

Comment: It should work fine, provide Xcode and iOS versions

Answer (score 2):

Most probably the reason of this issue is somewhere you are overriding the `UILabel` Property in your code. when you remove that code, it definitely works.

If you don't override it then search following in your pod files. may be some of pod file override `UILabel` property for their use.

```
extension UILabel {
    ...
    override open func draw(_ rect: CGRect) { ... }
    override open var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize { ... }
    ...
}
```